# join condition order

Tags: join

Given a simple query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a a 
inner join table_b b on b.id_from_a = a.id
```

Does the order of the `on` clause matters? In the example above I always put the recently joined table on the left side of the equal sign and on the right side I put the first table

Would

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a a 
inner join table_b b on a.id = b.id_from_a
```

perform the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never matters at all. Use whichever style you prefer.